# Frequent 504 Gateway Timeout errors in Microsoft Graph message api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I keep getting these for almost every request I make:

```
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphFatalServiceException: Unexpected exception returned from the service.GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/messages?$filter=IsDraft+eq+false+and+ReceivedDateTime+ge+2017-09-06T12%3a02%3a26.608Z&$orderby=ReceivedDateTime+desc&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties(%24filter%3did+eq+%27String+0x7D%27)%2cattachments&$select=conversationId%2cchangeKey%2csentDateTime%2creceivedDateTime%2cisRead%2chasAttachments%2cinternetMessageHeaders%2csender%2cfrom%2ctoRecipients%2cccRecipients%2cbccRecipients%2csubject%2cinternetMessageId%2cbody%2cattachments&$top=100&$skip=6426
SdkVersion : graph-java-v0.2.0
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI[...]
client-request-id : 38246tl5hwutoukh6qb

504 : Gateway Timeout
```

Any chance on getting it resolved?

Comment: Hi Dor, Could you provide your custom properties? For now, I'm not able to reproduce the issue with information you've provided. Thanks

Comment: @kikang what do you mean by custom properties?

Comment: my apology, on second thought, we should try to break your message apart and troubleshooting it as add more and more message. As for now, we can not reproduce the issue with infomation you've provided. And i'm cruious on how frequent do you get this 504 error. And when you successfully run it how the messages are different than the one that fails.

Comment: I lowered $top to 50 which reduced the error frequency but they still occur.
For example, this request always returns 504 error:
/users/me/messages?$filter=IsDraft+eq+false+and+ReceivedDateTime+ge+2017-09-26T12%3a40%3a15.691Z&$orderby=ReceivedDateTime+desc&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties(%24filter%3did+eq+%27String+0x7D%27)%2cattachments&$select=conversationId%2cchangeKey%2csentDateTime%2creceivedDateTime%2cisRead%2chasAttachments%2cinternetMessageHeaders%2csender%2cfrom%2ctoRecipients%2cccRecipients%2cbccRecipients%2csubject%2cinternetMessageId%2cbody%2cattachments&$top=50&$skip=2339

Comment: In your request, you have add the attachments and body in select parameter, it will have a large response when you have some large attachments in the messages. So you can try remove the attachments in the request url